# Where is the source-code to define the phase of surefire plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

As most of Java developers know, by default the *execution phase* of `maven-surefire-plugin` is `test`, which is of the same value of `goal`

**Question**: where is this part of logic in the `maven-surefire-plugin` [source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to know the default phase of the `test` goal: it's [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/9b7ecf141f4686c094219038272c28fecccffa30/maven-surefire-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefirePlugin.java#L45)

The default phase for a goal is part of the Mojo annotation that you use when [writing maven plugins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) (which is a good read before embarking in looking at the insides of maven plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally `surefire:test` goal is bind by default to `test` phase.

You can more read at [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Such default lifecycles and bindings are defined in Maven core itself.